# How can i create a game that alternated between players?

Tags: python

I am looking to make a guess my number game that alternates between the user guessing and the Al but I'm not sure how to do it. I already have a guess my number game code but I don't know what to add to make it change from user to computer.

```
#Guess my number

import random

print ("Welcome to the guess my number game")
print ("***********************************")
print ("I will choose a random number between 1-100")
print ("and you must guess what it is.")
print ()

number = random.randint(1,100)
guesses = 0
guess = 0

while guess != number:
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    guesses=guesses+1

    if guess > number:
        print("Lower...")
        continue

    elif guess < number:
        print ("Higher...")

    else:
        print ("Well done you have guessed my number and it took you", guesses,"guesses!")

input ("\n\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Comment: The code does work I have tried and tested it many times.

Comment: You should add code to retrieve (and check) a guess from the AI to the loop body. Code snippets are not intended to be used with Python: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

```
guesses = [[],[]]
for player in itertools.cycle([0,1]):
    if player == 0:
         guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    else: 
         guess = computer_guess()
    guesses[player].append(guess)
    if guess == number:

       break
    if guess > number:
        print("Lower...")
        continue

    elif guess < number:
        print ("Higher...")

print "Player %d wins"%player
print "It Took %d guesses"%len(guesses[player])
```

maybe what you are looking for